# Anyone know how to get older versions of chrome for Mac?

Tags: google-chrome, mac

I need to get older versions of Chrome - not chromium - for Mac OS X specifically, 86 & 83 and all the guides online are for windows users. I'm fine to download from third-party sites but only a couple of blatant scams pop up for google searches.

Comment: The only link is chromium, stupid question but is Chromium the same as chrome for using - outside of extensions. I need a Chrome 86 user agent when browsing and if Chromium can provide this / not show websites I am using chromium and not chrome then I will use chromium 86

Comment: Both Chrome (Never Provided) and Chromium has stopped proving old versions because there are some security issues with them.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the User Agent to be sent in a specific format, you can change it in Safari, to whatever you want it to be, from the Develop menu.

Open Safari Prefs > Advanced to enable the Develop menu
Then Develop > User Agent > Other… & you can type any agent string you like

[image]

[image]

First string is real, second is 'fake'. (I didn't check version/build for accuracy)